# Fetch values inserted into a MySQL table during last hour and current hour

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am doing this using Laravel 5. I want to fetch the rows that were inserted into the MySQL table during last hour and current hour.

[image]

The time column datetime format is like this: `2015-11-11 08:34:25`,
and I want to get current hour and fetch data that was inserted to the table during the current hour. How can I do this?

Now I have edited my code

Now I have edited
[image]

and no error but fetching rows not during last and current hour

Comment: so, you can generate the date/time string using php's `date()` function, then just add a WHERE condition in your query that says `WHERE time > $one_hour_ago`

Comment: It would help if the code provided was in text rather than an image. What error are you getting from the code?

Comment: $RecentTrips= $TripDetails= DriverTrips::select('*')
            ->where('driverid',$id)
            ->where('time','>=','DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR')
            ->where('date',$dateoFTrip)
            ->where('status','=','accepted')
            ->orwhere('status','=','late')
            ->get();

Comment: no any error but fetching data not in correct duration

Comment: I have do that in this way also  $daterecent = new DateTime;
 $daterecent->modify('-3600 minutes');
 $formatted_date = $daterecent->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 
   $RecentTrips= $TripDetails= DriverTrips::select('*')
            ->where('driverid',$id)
            ->where('time','<',$formatted_date)
            ->where('date',$dateoFTrip)
            ->where('status','=','accepted')
            ->orwhere('status','=','late')
            ->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a typo: you wrote `>whereBetween` instead of `->whereBetween`

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'HOUR(time)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Drivertripdetails` where `driverid` = 9 and `date` = 2015-11-11 and `status` = accepted or `status` = late and `HOUR(time)` between 2015-11-11 13:34:07 and 2015-11-11 12:34:07)   now I got tis error.Thanx for help.

Comment: You should use `DB::raw("HOUR(time)")`

Comment: I cant figure it out I access the db using the model Tripdetails .can kindly explain this

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what I should explain.

Comment: $RecentTrips=DriverTrips::select('*')
            ->where('driverid',$id)
            ->where('date',$dateoFTrip)
            ->where('status','=','accepted')
            ->orwhere('status','=','late')
            ->whereBetween('time', [$currentHour, $lasthour])
            ->get();

Comment: can you ask a question?

Comment: can you please refer my edited question now i have edited that on above

Comment: Since I don't know your data, I suggest you write the SQL query upfront, e.g. using phpMyAdmin. If you still don't get any results, you could debug it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve the question like this

```
enter code here 
    $currentHour=carbon::now()->toTimeString();
    $lasthour=carbon::now()->subHour()->toTimeString();

    $RecentTrips=DriverTrips::select('*')
        ->where('driverid',$id)
        ->where('date',$dateoFTrip)
        ->where(function($query){

            $query->orwhere('status','=','accepted')
                  ->orwhere('status','=','late');
        })

        ->where(function($query)use ($currentHour,$lasthour){

            $query ->whereRaw('TIME(time) <?',[$currentHour])
                   ->whereRaw('TIME(time) >?',[$lasthour]);
        })

        ->get();
```